# R: Turn Row into a Label for Column Names Then Remove Row

Tags: r

I have a large data set and I was wondering how I would take my second line of data and turn that value into a label for the column that it is in and then remove that character data from my table.

A   B    C
1 X57 X29 X38
2 20  28   26
3 11  15  19

A   B    C
1 20  28   26
2 11  15  19

Comment: Please read [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), which is especially important when asking questions about reshaping data.frames.

Comment: this will only work if the length of the rows is the same as the number of columns.  Does nrow( x) == ncol(x)